# Hibernate reverse engineering with ReverseEngineeringStrategy

Tags: hibernate, logging

I'm using the Hibernate tools to revers engineer my database to Entity Objects. For this I use the eclipse Hibernate Code Generation with a revenge strategy to customize my Class and Field names, since my database tables use prefixes that I need to drop.

Problem: How do I ***log*** statements in my ReverseEngineering java file. ***I can't get the logging working.***

This is a part of my ReverseEngineering class:

```
public class HibernateReverseEngineering extends DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy {

private static final org.slf4j.Logger Logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateReverseEngineering.class);

public HibernateReverseEngineering(ReverseEngineeringStrategy delegate) {
    super(delegate);
}

@Override
public String columnToPropertyName(TableIdentifier table, String column) {
    if (column.length() > 5) {
        Logger.trace("Property name: changing from column name");
        return column.substring(5).toLowerCase();
    } else {
        Logger.trace("Property name: default from column name");
        return super.columnToPropertyName(table, column);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many places where this can go wrong, but I had a problem with hibernate and logging that may be present in your case, too.  The Hibernate pom declares a dependency on slf4j, but not on an implementation of the slf4j logging interface.  Therefore, you end up with a logging interface, but no implementation!

Include the following in your dependencies:

```
org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.5
```

Comment: I have a similar problem to OP, but adding slf4j-simple to my pom didn't solve the issue.  You mention many other places logging can go wrong.  Can you elaborate for me and OP?